# How do I grab env variables in expect?

Tags: expect, tclsh

For example, I would like to use $USER and $HOSTNAME which is defined when I login.
however

```tcl
set g_user [exec echo \$USER]
```

shows me only an error that \$USER is not recognizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `env` array is what you need:

```tcl
# if you use env in a procedure, you need to specify it is a global variable
global env
set g_user $env(USER)
```

Documented at http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm